# Does the number of photons in a displaced coherent state is same as the original coherent state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, photons, coherent-states

Lets say I receive a quantum state $|\alpha\rangle$ with number of photons $N$ and I displace this state by $\alpha$ $\hat D(\alpha)$ so the resultant state is $|2\alpha\rangle$ with same number of photons $N$ or $4N$ (as the number of photons is absolute value square).

Comment: Hi Chetan. I have attempted to tidy up the question by using MathJax for the symbols, but you might want to check my edit as I find it hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: (1) The number if photons in a coherent state is not definite (although there is a mean number of photons). (2) Your specification of the state and of your operation of the state is not precise enough. Displacement can mean different operations in the given context. BTW you can [typset math here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) properly typesetting your equations may help to clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

Coherent states are eigenstates of the annihilation operator:
$$ \hat{a}|\alpha\rangle = |\alpha\rangle \alpha . $$
The adjoint of this equation gives:
$$ \langle\alpha|\hat{a}^{\dagger} = \alpha^*\langle\alpha| . $$
The number operator $\hat{n}=\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}$ counts the average number of photons in a state. Using the above two equations, we get
$$ \langle\alpha|\hat{n}|\alpha\rangle = \langle\alpha|\hat{a}^{\dagger} \hat{a}|\alpha\rangle = \alpha^*\langle\alpha|\alpha\rangle \alpha = |\alpha|^2, $$
because coherent states are normalized $\langle\alpha|\alpha\rangle =1$.

So, if you started with a coherent state $|\alpha\rangle$ having an average number of $|\alpha|^2=N$ photons and you displace this coherent state to $|2\alpha\rangle$, then it would have an average number of $|2\alpha|^2=4N$ photons.

A beamsplitter can be used to displace a coherent state. For this purpose one would use another coherent state. Consider the tensor product $|\alpha\rangle_A|\alpha'\rangle_B$ as input for the two input ports (labeled $A$ and $B$) of a 50:50 beamsplitter. Here $|\alpha\rangle$ is the coherent state that we want to displace and $|\alpha'\rangle$ is the one with which we are going to displace it. The output of the beamsplitter is the tensor product:
$$\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\alpha
+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\alpha'\right\rangle_A
\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\alpha
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\alpha'\right\rangle_B . $$
The two coherent states at the two output ports are both displaced. If $\alpha'=\alpha$, then we can have perfect constructive interference in one output port and perfect destructive interference in the other. Hence, the output becomes $|\sqrt{2}\alpha\rangle_A|0\rangle_B$. The displaced coherent state at output port $A$ will then have twice the number of photons as the original coherent state while the other output port produces a vacuum state. Of course it is not so easy to get such perfect constructive and destructive inference in physical experiments.

Comment: flippiefanus How I have to imagine the photon doubling?  Photons are indivisible during their life. Independent of what math tells you. Furthermore interference is a math construct too, mostly  photons do not interact. Sorry for being pertinent.

Comment: There are no photons created in the process. The photons that enter the beamsplitter from the two input port are combined into the same output port to give a state with more photons. Interference does not mean interactions. It is a coherent superposition that causes an enhancement.

Answer (score -2):

Whatever mathematical constructs say, more fundamental is the understanding that photons are invariant quanta from their emission to their absorption.

As long as there are no subatomic particles in an observation volume from which the photons are absorbed and re-emitted, the number of photons between entering and leaving that volume remains the same.

Comment: That is what I would have thought, but I think the question is within quantum optics , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_operator  . It is the meaning of the D that makes the difference, extra real 0 mass photons are generated with the displacement.

Comment: A coherent state can be displaced with the aid of a beamsplitter

Comment: @flippiefanus Please teach me, how a beamsplitter changes the number of photons.

Comment: See the edit in my answer.